# Why can't I return a reference from this template function?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, return-type

I took this example straight out of a book ([Sams Teach Yourself C++ in One Hour a Day](https://books.google.com/books/about/Sams_Teach_Yourself_C++_in_One_Hour_a_Da.html?id=JUT-rDb5R1UC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

```
// Get the maximum of two values
template <typename objectType>
objectType& GetMax(const objectType& value1, const objectType& value2)
{
    if (value1 > value2)
        return value1;
    else
        return value2;
}
```

Essentially it is a very verbosely written template function to find the maximum between 2 values of any type.

I attempted to use the function as follows:

```
// Test the Max function
int x_int = 25;
int y_int = 40;
int max_int = GetMax(x_int, y_int);
cout << "max_int: " << max_int << endl;

double x_double = 1.1;
double y_double = 1.001;
double max_double = GetMax(x_double, y_double);
cout << "max_double: " << max_double << endl;
```

However, when I attempt to compile and run the code I get the following errors:

> Error  1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'
>
> Error  2   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'
>
> Error  3   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const double' to 'double &'
>
> Error  4   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const double' to 'double &'

---

If I simply remove the `&` from the return type of the function it will compile and execute successfully.

Why can't I return a reference from this function?  Is the book wrong, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: You should be returning a `const&`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is the `const` part of the argument declaration. The variables `value1` and `value2` are references to *constant* values, but you return a reference to a non-constant value.

Comment: That's it! The strange thing is after I added "const" to it, Visual Studio decided to underline it in red for about 10 seconds making me think it was an error even though it wasnt... *facepalm*

Answer (score 5):

The error explains it all, you can't return a non-const reference to a const reference.

```
// Get the maximum of two values
template <typename objectType>
const objectType& GetMax(const objectType& value1, const objectType& value2)
{
    if (value1 > value2)
        return value1;
    else
        return value2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate what lines the errors refer to (as well as post a complete program that others can just copy/paste into their editor).

But I expect them to refer to this line

```
return value1;
```

and the similar one after it. The errors tell you exactly what is wrong:

```
cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'
```

And sure enough, if we investigate the details of what this line is trying to do, we see that the thing you are trying to return is const:

```
const objectType& value1
```

but the type the function promises to return is a nonconst refernce:

```
objectType& GetMax
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function `GetMax` is a reference, but you're attempting to return a variable that is a `const` reference.

That is not allowed and compilation fails.

Attempting to circumvent this mechanism using a `const_cast` on `value1` and `value2` is dangerous since the behaviour on casting away `const`ness from an value that was originally `const` is undefined.

The obvious thing to do is to change the return type of `GetMax` to a `const` reference.